# RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED with Vertex Pipeline by leveraging the free trial on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am fairly new to GCP and I am playing around with it taking advantage of the free trial.

I would like to run [this simple pipeline](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/vertex-pipelines-intro#4) in Vertex from notebook, but once I run it, I get this error in the very first task.

`com.google.cloud.ai.platform.common.errors.AiPlatformException: code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, message=The following quota metrics exceed quota limits: aiplatform.googleapis.com/custom_model_training_cpus, cause=null;`

I've looked at the quotas of the error and I have 1 CPU for each available region. Of course I can not edit them, because of the free trial.

I also made these other attempts without success:

- Set the CPU limit equal to 1 on the pipeline component;
- Use the less powerful machine available (n1-standard-4, which actually uses 4 vCPUs);
- Run the pipeline in different regions;
- Define and run the pipeline in a completely new project;
- Define and run the AutoML pipeline for classification/regression, starting from the available models.

It seems rather strange to me that it is not possible to try this service with free trial, but I don't know how to solve the problem. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which regions have you tried? You can check the regions available of the resource in question at the Quotas page within your project. go to "IAM & Admin" > "Quotas" then go find the resource at the search bar:

[image]

Another alternative is to request a quota increase, be aware though that there that quota increase request will go though evaluation before getting granted. For more information about conditions about quota you can visit Google's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#running_out).

Comment: I tried some of the asian and us regions available for Vertex Pipeline (the same I can see available in the quotas). As already said, I am not able to request a quota increase beacause of the free trial.

Comment: If that is the case I would suggest contacting sales instead, Request for the resource and possible ways to get your request granted. https://cloud.google.com/contact